# Routing to class object in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Is it possible to create a route, calling a controller method with a class?

In this sample, i'm hitting the `GetPerson` method, but person is always null.

I'm using a GET

```
WebApiConfig
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "person",
                    routeTemplate: "person/{firstName}/{lastName}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Person", action = "GetPerson" });
```

Controller

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetPerson(Person person)
            {
                // person always null here
                //DO STUFF!
            }
```

Model

```
public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a reference, telling the Controller where to get Person from.

In your case add `[FromUri]` to your Parameter like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetPerson([FromUri] Person person)
    {
            //DO STUFF!
    }
```

You can read up on Parameterbinding in Asp.Net [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)